# Regrading GridTemplateColumn in Radgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik-grid

Now i have trying to bind value in GridTemplateColumn with asp.net lable, telerik lable and html but does not display value in column

I am using following code to bind column. I am using telerik version Q3 2011

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn" HeaderText="Template Column">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text="<%# Eval("Assignment_ID") %>" runat="server"   ID="Label1" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Please give solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%"
        HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" UniqueName="Status" DataField='MstUserDefineCode.Code'>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="LabelStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectStatus") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

You can use like this.